# YouTube Auto Comment?

Tags: youtube, comments

I have been trying to make something that automatically comments on a YouTube video. So far i have attempted thiswitch , Im new at scripting so plz forgive me.

```
enter code here
// ==UserScript==
// @name         YouTube auto chat
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Auto comments on all youtube videos you open
// @author       BoBgames
// @match        https://www.youtube.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(comment) {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    function partA(w) {
  window.setTimeout(partB,10000);
}

function partB() {
}
    document.getElementById(".comment-simplebox-render-collapsed-content").click();

    $("comment-simplebox-render-collapsed-content").sendkeys('1234');
    $("comment-simplebox-render-collapsed-content").focus();
})();
```

Im not sure im trying to call the right element or if im even doing this correctly.

Comment: First read on [jquery selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)  . Use the correct notation for the jQuery selectors and the correct notation for `.getElementById` .

Comment: you wouldnt happen to know what the click box element for the "add comment" is would you?